# JProgressBar in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, jprogressbar

I added a progress bar to my text pane but I cannot re-size the width of the progress bar added (can re-size height). could you please help me with this issue and also tell me how can I remove the progress bar once I am done with it.

```
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 15));
progressBar.setMinimum(0);
progressBar.setMaximum((int) file.length());

textPane.setSelectionStart(textPane.getText().length());
textPane.setSelectionEnd(textPane.getText().length());
textPane.insertComponent(progressBar);
```

Comment: How I'd solve the last issue (removing the progress bar): create the progress bar once (when creating the form), make it hidden, show/hide it when needed. P.S. Please note: I'm not familiar with the GUI library you are using but this is how most GUI frameworks work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are questioning about how to set your preferred width for the `JProgressBar`, right?

If this is your question, you should use `setMaximumSize` instead of `setPreferredSize`:

```
JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
//progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 15));
progressBar.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(50, 15)); // This line instead of above line
progressBar.setMinimum(0);
progressBar.setMaximum((int) file.length());
```

**[EDIT]**
For removing components you should assume the components in your `JTextPane` as some characters, and then remove them from `JTextPane's Document` object. I also assumed a temp `JButton` to raise the remove event:

```
JButton b = new JButton("Remove!");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                textPane.getDocument().remove(0, 1);
            } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you it worked. If it is not too much to ask could you tell me how I can remove it from the text pane also.

Comment: Something that can be useful to know if you start inserting components in the JTextPane : The component is stored in the `ComponentAttribute`. You can get it with : `StyleConstants.getComponent` or using `getAttribute` with `StyleConstants.ComponentAttribute`. It can be useful to find a component when you don't know its offset ;)